# Size of evaluation stack in CPython

Tags: python, memory-management, stack

I am aware that CPython has a recursion limit, which on my copy of Python is 3000.

Does anyone know if there is a limit to the stack depth when doing arithmetic evaluations?

Does CPython uses the same stack for function calls and the evaluation stack?

Most other laguages do so I assume CPython does as well. Since CPython doesn't store much on the stack (almost everything I belive is kept on the heap), I imagine the evaluation stack need not be too large? I searched https://leanpub.com/insidethepythonvirtualmachine but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research and it appears that there are multiple evaluation (or value) stacks in CPython. For example, When CPython calls a function, a PyFrameObject is instantiated and within that, an evaluation stack is created for the function.  The size of this stack is apparently estimated at compile time. In summary, there is no single evaluation stack and the size for each one is estimated at compile time.